Date of birth day without English ordinal suffix for the day of the month ('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th')
In the contact's date of birth display, View Contact, the days of the month are shown with the English suffixes ('st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'). I would like to remove these suffixes in the Italian display. Is there a setting to eliminate these suffixes from the display in languages other than English?

The date format for Birth date is managed in Settings - Date Preferences(CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Date Preferences)

You choose any date format you would like and make sure the Date Format: Complete Date under Date Formats(CiviCRM >> Administer >> Localization >> Date Formats) is not using %f
HTH
Pradeep

Thank you Pradeep, solved

Can you mark as Answered so that it can help others in the community?
